# How to make C++ linking take less memory

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linker

I am working on a university research project in C++ with **a lot** of templates which have further nested templates and so on. The project is about efficient index data structures for a specific area of research. You can imagine: An index structure has a lot of parameters to adjust, so we use the template parameters excessively. Of course, we want to test our indexes with different sets of parameters, so there are quite a lot of template instantiations.

The project is not that huge. Maybe 50k LOC. But still, linking take 50 seconds and consumes over 7 GB memory (!!!). I am on a 32GB workstation so everything is fine for me. I often have bachelor and master students working on this project. The problem is that they often work on Laptops with 4 or 8 GB of RAM. Thus, these students have great troubles compiling that project. The resulting test binary (i.e. a binary that simply contains unit tests for the index structures) is 700 megabytes. 
Most of that are symbols, because the nested templates produce huge names. If I use `strip` on the binary, it drops down to 8 megabytes.

So is there a way to reduce the RAM usage during linkage? And is there a way to have smaller symbols even with nested templates?

We compile using g++4.9 with `std=c++11` under Ubuntu 14.10.

Edit:

It really seems to be the nested templates. We have two test cases with really deeply nested templates. The two `.o` files for these test make up almost 90% of the memory of the final binary. They result in method names that are over 3000 characters long. There is no way to not use the nested templates here as they form a "processing tree" of an example query. Is there any way to keep names short when using deeply nested templates?

Comment: What OS, compiler version?

Comment: @EdChum: g++4.9 under Ubuntu 14.10. Added it to the question now.

Comment: Which C++ version? C++11 has external templates!

Comment: Try also some other compiler, e.g. a *recent* [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: We use C++11

Comment: Could you post the make file, one thing you could do is force it to be a single process during compilation and linking but it sounds like you have more fundamental issues here

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Wow, you are right! `clang++` only took 5 seconds and 1-2 Gigabytes. Why such a huge difference?

Comment: @EdChum: The makefile is huge and consists of 30 different files. I better not post it. The linker call is just one big `g++` call that links all `.o` files (around 30).

Comment: Just wondering if you have a `-j` flag set in your make files: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html, sounds like using clang would be a better move at this point

Comment: "The linker call is just one big g++ call that links all .o files". Perhaps partitioning into libraries would reduce memory requirements.

Comment: If possible, make a bug report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla

Comment: "we want to test our indexes with different sets of parameters" - perhaps a number of small test programs might be better than one huge one?

Answer (score 4):

GCC has a garbage collection scheme for the RAM it uses.

The parameters `ggc-min-expand` and `ggc-min-heapsize` are used to determine when GCC should clean up and dealloc its unused memory (their defaults are percentages of the total system memory).

You could try something like:

```
g++ --param ggc-min-expand=0 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192
```

From the GCC manual:

> **ggc-min-expand**
>
> GCC uses a garbage collector to manage its own memory allocation. This parameter specifies the minimum percentage by which the garbage
> collector's heap should be allowed to expand between collections.
> Tuning this may improve compilation speed; it has no effect on code
> generation.
>
> The default is 30% + 70% * (RAM/1GB) with an upper bound of 100% when RAM >= 1GB. If getrlimit is available, the notion of "RAM" is the
> smallest of actual RAM, RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_DATA and RLIMIT_AS. If GCC
> is not able to calculate RAM on a particular platform, the lower bound
> of 30% is used. Setting this parameter and ggc-min-heapsize to zero
> causes a full collection to occur at every opportunity. This is
> extremely slow, but can be useful for debugging.
>
> **ggc-min-heapsize**
>
> Minimum size of the garbage collector's heap before it begins
> bothering to collect garbage. The first collection occurs after the
> heap expands by ggc-min-expand% beyond ggc-min-heapsize. Again, tuning
> this may improve compilation speed, and has no effect on code
> generation.
> The default is RAM/8, with a lower bound of 4096 (four megabytes) and an upper bound of 131072 (128 megabytes). If getrlimit is
> available, the notion of "RAM" is the smallest of actual RAM,
> RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_DATA and RLIMIT_AS. If GCC is not able to calculate
> RAM on a particular platform, the lower bound is used. Setting this
> parameter very large effectively disables garbage collection. Setting
> this parameter and ggc-min-expand to zero causes a full collection to
> occur at every opportunity.

Further details:

- [Compiling with GCC on low memory VPS](https://web.archive.org/web/20200420190418/http://hostingfu.com/article/compiling-with-gcc-on-low-memory-vps)

Comment: while it's maybe not the main problem, this approach wouldn't reduce linking time but most probably increase it a little bit

Comment: You're right, there is a trade-off between linking time and memory consumption. Moreover the "optimal" values can vary.

Answer (score 3):

> So is there a way to reduce the RAM usage during linkage? And is there a way to have smaller symbols even with nested templates?

Have you considered using the **pimpl idiom** in client code?

Consider a situation where you have this include chain:

A.h -> B.h -> C.h -> D.h (C includes D, B includes C, etc)

Suppose that A.h defines class AA, B.h defines class B and so on (with AA implemented in terms of BB, BB implemented in terms of CC and so on).

If DD is a large template and used in the implementation of CC, the templated code will be compiled three times, for the compilation units A, B and C.

Now, consider what happens if instead of C.h including D.h, you have the following situation:

C.h foward declares a `CCImpl *pimpl` and forwards all it's methods to `pImpl->` methods (and does not include D.h).

C.cpp includes C.h and D.h, and implements `CCImpl` and `CC`.

Now, D will be included *once* (and compiled once, for C.cpp). A and B will only include C.h, with a CImpl forward declaration. A.h, B.h and C.h no longer know that a template exists.

Comment: I have considered this, thanks. The problem is that our university project is about measuring the performance of these very low level very efficient data structures. Thus, we cannot even pay the price of an additional dereferentiation (and the failed inlining possibilities that come with it). We are sometimes down to even counting average cycles and having only a few ten cycles per operation.

Answer (score 2):

Use inheritance judiciously. You may have a `class Foo<1,4,8,1,9,int, std::string>` as a base class for `class Bar`, and then the object file will mention just `Bar`.

Note that `typedef` does not introduce names for linking purposes.

[edit]
And to address a performance concern from another comment, an empty derived class adds no overhead on common compilers at normal optimization levels (and often there's no overhead even in debug builds)